# Find first instance of NOT integer in an array

Tags: c, arrays, integer

So I know the memchr command returns a pointer to to the first instance of an integer given the pointer to an array. I want to know if there is a similar command, or an equally fast way to return a pointer to the first instance in memory where there isn't a given integer.

For example, if I had an array filled with the integer 30, except at one index, where there is a 5, it returns the pointer to where the 5 is stored.

Comment: There is no such standard function, you need to implement it yourself. And btw, why `memchr( array, 5, size )` would not work?

Comment: `memchar` does byte by byte search and not recommended for searching integer if size of int is more than byte. Why don't you write a simple for loop to search?

Comment: When you say *if I had an array filled with the integer 30* - what exactly do you mean? Can you please show a code with defining such an array?

Comment: Although `memchr` takes an argument `int c`, it is searching for a **byte** value, all of which are integers.

Comment: @Renat. It needs to return the pointer to any number that isn't 30. If I don't know the number, I can't use memchr.

Comment: @kiran Biradar I'm using an unsigned char array. So I assume memchr, or something related should be recommended? I am currently using a loop, but it's the biggest bottleneck in terms of speed in my code.

Comment: @Weather Vane thanks, I actually didn't know that. But to be clear, I'm actually searching through an unsigned char array, which is 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a string...

```
#include <stddef.h>
char *my_strcchr(char *s, int c) {
    while (*s && (*s == c)) s++;
    return *s ? s : NULL;
}
```